# Windows: Fastest way of killing a process running on a specific port

Tags: windows, process, kill

I am going over this process many times. I have to kill a process on a Windows machine and I just know its port. 
Normally the steps are as below: Find the PID by looking at the ports (example port 8084)    List the processes running on ports

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

And then kill the process on that port with the following command

```
taskkill /F /PID <pid>
```

Is there any thing like a pipe or similar that I can use on Windows OS to run this command in one line!?

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't write a full answer right now, but have a look at `findstr` (the Windows `grep`). For example: `netstat -a -o -n | findstr "LISTENING" | findstr ":135"`. Maybe this gets you a step closer ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Need to be careful with that 2nd `findstr`: might match either local or remote port number. (Accepting that the Q doesn't specify which.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any thing like a pipe or similar that I can use on Windows OS to run this command in one line?

Both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell support pipes from one command to another. In PowerShell something like (this should be on a single line on the command line, or use ` to escapte newlines in a script):

```
netstat -ano
 | select -skip 4 
 | % {$a = $_ -split ' {3,}'; New-Object 'PSObject' -Property @{Original=$_;Fields=$a}} 
 | ? {$_.Fields[1] -match '15120$'}
 | % {taskkill /F /PID $_.Fields[4] }
```

Where:

- `Select -skip 4` skips the first four header lines. (`Select` is short for `Select-Object` used to perform SQL SELECT like projects of objects.
- `%` is short for `Foreach-Object` which performs a script block on each object (`$_`) in the pipeline and outputs the results of the script block to the pipeline. Here it is first breaking up the input into an array of fields and then creating a fresh object with two properties `Original` the string from `netstat` and `Fields` the array just created.
- `?` is short for `Where-Object` which filters based on the result of a script block. Here matching a regex at the end of the second field (all PowerShell containers a zero based).

(All tested except the last element: I don't want to start killing processes :-)).

In practice I would simplify this, eg. returning just 0 or the PID from the first `foreach` (which would be designed to ignore the headers) and filter on value not zero before calling `taskkill`. This would be quicker to type but harder to follow without knowing PowerShell.

Comment: for some reason my powershell does not recognize the select! Running Windows 7
    "Der Befehl "select" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden."

Same for "Select-Object"

Comment: This worked for me, but the process is found twice, I believe due to IPv4 and IPv6 versions being listed by `netstat`. This leads to a (probably harmless) error of `ERROR: The process "12345" not found.`.

Comment: I think the important takeaway here is `taskkill /F /PID [PID]`. With that, someone can manually kill tasks so long as they have a way of getting the PID.

Answer (score 3):

Open command prompt and execute:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon | find "8080"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

If you want to do it in a batch file instead, replace `%a` with `%%a` and `|` with `^|`.

If you just want to kill the one that is listening on that port append `| find "LISTENING"` at the end of the other find.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a convenient function that you can use:

https://github.com/majkinetor/posh/blob/master/MM_Network/Stop-ProcessByPort.ps1

```
killp 8081
```